# Pushfd and Pushad: What's the point?

Tags: assembly, x86, 32bit-64bit

I know that pushad pushes all the 32 bit registers onto the stack, but the only register that ends up being stored on the stack is EDI. Flag values aren't affected so what's the point of using pushad? Additionally, I know that pushfd pushes all flag values in a double format. So, if flag values are usually only 0 or 1 how does the pushfd operation push a value such as 00000A46 to the stack?

Comment: "the only register that ends up being stored on the stack is EDI" - How did you arrive at that conclusion?

Comment: Not sure where you get that.  You use pusha and pushf in 16-bit code, pushad and pushfd in 32-bit code.  A46 has 12 bits.

Comment: This question makes no sense. The EDI bit is not true, please give an explanation of tha part. Flags are not affected by what? What's a "double format"? Are you talking about flags or the EFLAGS register? Also, are we in 32 or 16 bit code? Etc.

Comment: EDI is the last register loaded onto the stack and if you have used this in x86 assembly at all, it is the only value stored on the stack.

Comment: @user1210446 Your misunderstanding comes from the fact that `pusha` decrements `esp`  between each write to the stack, thus all the pushed registers end up on different addresses.

Answer (score 40):

> ...the only register that ends up being stored on the stack is EDI.

No. The PUSHAD instruction *always* pushes *all* 8 general purpose registers onto the stack. A single PUSHAD instruction is equivilent to writing:

```
Push EAX
Push ECX
Push EDX
Push EBX
Push ESP
Push EBP
Push ESI
Push EDI
```

POPAD pops the values back off the stack in reverse order, thus restoring all the register values.

PUSHAD and POPAD are useful for performing a easy save and restore of the general purpose registers without having to PUSH and POP every individual register in turn.

Similarly, PUSHFD and POPFD are used to save and restore the EFLAGS register. Although not really used that much in ordinary programs, the instructions are useful when (for example) a process context switch is performed (or anywhere else where the value of the flags register must be restored).

> how does the pushfd operation push a value such as 00000A46 to the stack?

It's just how the data is interpreted. The EFLAGS register is a set of 32 bits. If you divide the bits up into 8 groups of 4 (8*4=32), you can map each 4 bit chunk to a hexadecimal character (0..9,A-F). Likewise, you can convert the hexadecimal values back to a set of bits:

00000A46  = 0000(0) 0000(0) 0000(0) 0000(0) 0000(0) 1010(A) 0100(4) 0110(6)

These are the values of the bits that were stored in the EFLAGS register.

Comment: You can get reference to this here https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_270.html